# How to custom ID (_id) in MongoDB in PHP7 ? i don't see here http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Tags: mongodb, php-7

Hye,

How make to custom ID (_id) in new driver MongoDB for PHP7 ?
I don't see here
http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Thx for advance!

Comment: What do you mean? There is and never was any function to set a custom _id. You have to do it yourself with http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php

Comment: Sorry, Yes i can personalize as i want :) AWS!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Yes i can personalize as i want. Where is MongoRegex class in MongoDB Driver to make Regex?
http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mongodb.php

Comment: FYI if you need to ask another question, please start another question.